# Retrieve correct (full) html

Tags: java, android, html

My goal is to retrieve a website's `html`, and to convert it into a readable `String`. The code I have below works, but I am encountering a technical issue: when I try retrieving the `html` of http://time.gov/HTML5, the `String` I get on my android output is different than the `html` I see on the website (the `html` that I see when I right click the page and click `Inspect Element` on Google Chrome). Specifically, when I use `Inspect Element`, I see a section of the `html` code that looks like

```
<div class="lzswftext" style="font-family: Arial, Verdana; font-weight: bold; pointer-events: none; width: 319px; height: 60px; font-size: 50px; line-height: 60px;">12:35:54 p.m.</div>
```

However, on my android output, I do not see anything like this (there is no "time" text [XX:XX:XX] at all). Does anyone know why this is occurring, and how I can fix it to get the same `html` that appears on `Inspect Element` on my android output?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
        task.execute("http://time.gov/HTML5");

    }

    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            HttpResponse response = null;
            HttpGet httpGet = null;
            HttpClient mHttpClient = null;
            String s = "";

            try {
                if(mHttpClient == null){
                    mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                }


                httpGet = new HttpGet(urls[0]);


                response = mHttpClient.execute(httpGet);
                s = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            return s;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            final TextView textview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.headline);
            textview1.setText(result);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: By right clicking and choosing view source you don't see that which you had pointed out.  I assume that is what you are getting back that it matches up against. You are probably referencing the changing variable i.e. time that this website updates through inspect element.

Comment: @JaySnayder I saw the changing variable when I used `Inspect Element`, but I wasn't expecting a changing variable in my android output; instead, I was looking for a set time [XX:XX:XX] representing the time at which I retrieved the html

Comment: are you sure this site not rendering differently for mobile devices?

Comment: @xjaphx, it appears to render the same way

Answer (score 1):

If anything is "the proper HTML", it's the original HTML page that you get from the server (which you correctly achieve). What you see with "inspect element" in a browser is the result of scripts modifying that original page dynamically in the browser (which may or may not involve further interaction with the original server or any others, for that matter).

In particular, http://time.gov/HTML5 uses JavaScript to accomplish what it does. Your code just fetches the HTML page, which indeed does not have any "time text" in the `div` you mention. It's only after an actual browser additionally executes the embedded JavaScript code, downloads some additional included script files and executes those, that any time gets output to the `div` element.

You cannot expect to see the results of scripts in the "original" HTML that you get from the server. I do not think you have a sane (as in easy and safe) way of parsing the HTML from the response and executing its scripts but I might be mistaken.

If you are trying to get the current time and are not just using the above site as an example, there are surely better ways to achieve what you want. For example, take a look [here](http://www.timeapi.org/).

Comment: TL;DR Inspect: Document + javascript. Source: Original HTML. +1

Answer (score 1):

Well, as I look up from the source, there is this part.

```
<div id="appcontainer"></div><div id="lzsplash" style="z-index: 10000000; top: 0; left: 0; width: 430px; height: 200px; position: fixed; display: table"><p style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;"></p></div><script type="text/javascript" defer>
              lz.embed.resizeWindow('430', '200');
              lz.embed.dhtml({url: 'nist_time.lzx.js', lfcurl: 'lps/includes/lfc/LFCdhtml.js', serverroot: 'lps/resources/', bgcolor: '#ffffff', width: '430', height: '200', id: 'lzapp', accessible: 'false', cancelmousewheel: false, cancelkeyboardcontrol: false, skipchromeinstall: false, usemastersprite: false, approot: '', appenddivid: 'appcontainer'});
              lz.embed.applications.lzapp.onload = function loaded() {
                // called when this application is done loading
                var el = document.getElementById('lzsplash');
                if (el.parentNode) {
                    el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
                }
              }
            </script>
```

That means, after loading the original HTML, it gonna take a while to load another script to embed the additional element for time. Therefore, the parsing fails.
I have no idea to do this, but I can suggest a hack, which is, using a `WebView`, and get the HTML source after finishing page-loading on `onPageFinished()`.